# Writing a Trigger to find and fill the age of a patient whenever a patient record is inserted into patients table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

In this question, I have to add value of age with the help of trigger.
please help me implement this question.

```
create or replace trigger ia_patient
after insert on patient
for each row
enable
declare
age_value number(10);
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Please Insert Age');
update patient set age=&age_value where ??;
end;
```

I am not sure what I should write after "where"

Comment: Does the PATIENT table have a column called DATE_OF_BIRTH or similar? Although this seems like a poor use for a trigger. In other words a classic homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is a *homework* question, it really doesn't make much sense as "age" depends on current date.

Anyway, see if this helps.

```
SQL> create table patient
  2    (id               number primary key,
  3     date_of_birth    date,
  4     age              number
  5    );

Table created.
```

Trigger: calculate age as months between sysdate and date of birth divided by 12 (as there are 12 months in a year); certainly, this is just an approximate value, but - as far as I understood - your task isn't to *correctly calculate* age, but to learn how to use triggers.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger ia_patient
  2    before insert on patient
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.age := round(months_between(sysdate, :new.date_of_birth) / 12);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into patient (id, date_of_birth) values (2, date '2000-10-05');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from patient;

        ID DATE_OF_BI        AGE
---------- ---------- ----------
         2 2000-10-05         20

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is written as a frame challenge to the question.

Don't use a trigger; if you do it'll insert the age now and then tomorrow, or in 6 months, or a year the person will have a birthday and your table will be incorrect. This should be something you calculate in a query at the time you want the data and could be put into a view.

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
  id            INTEGER
                GENERATED AS IDENTITY
                CONSTRAINT people__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name          VARCHAR2(50)
                NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth DATE
                NOT NULL
);
```

Then you can create a view to calculate the ages:

```sql
CREATE VIEW people_ages ( id, name, date_of_birth, age ) AS
SELECT id,
       name,
       date_of_birth,
       FLOOR( MONTHS_BETWEEN( SYSDATE, date_of_birth ) / 12 )
FROM   people;
```

Which, if you have the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO people ( name, date_of_birth )
SELECT 'Alice', DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob',   DATE '2020-10-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', DATE '2000-10-21' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output from the view would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM people_ages;
```

> ```
> ID | NAME  | DATE_OF_BIRTH       | AGE
> -: | :---- | :------------------ | --:
>  1 | Alice | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |  50
>  2 | Bob   | 2020-10-21 00:00:00 |   0
>  3 | Carol | 2000-10-21 00:00:00 |  20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6ba307e65622170477437deae35e934)*

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger has serious defects. Despite being a totally inappropriate use of a trigger I'll go over them.

1. Attribute: Age. Lets just say others have sufficiently covered it. But i will return to it.
2. DBMS_OUTPUT: This is **not** output when issued. The pl/sql engine does not even output this at all. It builds an internal buffer which can later be read back and processed by the client after the pl/sql has completed. However, there is no requirement that the client do so. Typically used for debugging purposes and not available in production system.
3. &age_value: This is an attempt at an interactive processing. Pl/sql **is not and cannot** do interactive processing. This is called a substitution variable and is totally the responsibly of the client. The client sees the &... and prompts for a value. It then physically alters the statement to contain that value. For example if you reply 42 to the prompt what is sent to the compiler is age=42. The compiler actually never sees &age_value.
4. Update: you **CAN NOT** do this; it will throw the exception "ORA-04091: table ... is mutating, trigger/function may not see it". Within a trigger you cannot issue DML on the table that caused the trigger to fire. Moreover it is completely unnecessary.
5. where ??: Since you cannot have the update statement this is moot.  

   In a trigger you refer to table columns through the pesudo rows :new and/or :old. So assuming you need to stay with a trigger you rewrite as (following assumes a date_of_birth column (dob) name being inserted):

```
create or replace trigger ia_patient
  after insert on patient
  for each row
  enable
begin
   :new.age := trunc(months_between(sysdate, :new.dob)/12);
end;
```

However the problem being age is now a static value. Which will need regular updates to keep current. A much better approach just let Oracle do the calculation when needed with a view as suggested by @MT0 and abandon the trigger altogether.